# Is it considered rude/unprofessional to reject a raise?

Tags: salary, raise

If I have been working at a company for a while and I am on a comfortable salary, and am offered a modest raise I do not feel is in line with my work, is it ok to refuse this?

I cannot find examples online of this scenario, so I am assuming this is a rare occurrence.

Comment: What do you mean "not in line with my work" - unrelated to your work, undeserved, not as high as you expect? -1 for lack of clarity.

Comment: Are you rejecting a raise or a promotion in responsibilities that is tied to the raise

Comment: The question is unclear. Are you turning it down in a "Keep your tiny raise, you jerk" way, or is it a "I don't think I deserve this much of a raise" way? What are your motivations for feeling this way? As it currently stands, your question doesn't provide enough detail to narrow the potential answer space down to anything helpful. Feel free to edit your question and clarify. This would be an interesting contribution to this site.

Comment: Unclear as to what you are asking. Too high or too low a raise?

Never turn down anything without having an open dialog. Don't be afraid to ask questions.

Comment: I don't think this was the intended circumstance, but suppose you are a top executive in a company and are offered a raise. If you already make enough money, maybe you could reject the raise for budgetary reasons or for PR benefit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably not rude or unprofessional, but certainly odd and likely to result in a conversation about why you feel this way. The company is giving you a raise for a reason: could be quality of you work, shift in the marketplace, movement in the internal salary landscape, seniority, autopilot, etc. You would somehow have to explain why this reason isn't applicable to you.

Depending how the conversation goes, this may impact your future career growth. In this case it may be better to just take the raise, say "thank you" and move on.

Answer (score 2):

In my country, when people get a raise that is not substantial (i.e. several hundred, to a couple of thousand), it happens that people reject the raise. The reason for this are the lovely tax scales. If you are just below a "new" scale, and the raise pushes you into the new scale, you could end up having to pay 10% tax *more*. Employers usually understand this if notified about it, and the employer and employee can negotiate about either a bonus or lower raise.

Comment: In the United States there are definitely situations where raising your income can change your *marginal* tax rate, and sometimes in unusual ways, but it is very rare for a raise to result in an increase in *effective* tax rate. That is to say, the increased tax rate usually only applies to *the new income*, so it is still a net win to the employee.  I am curious to know if you have a specific country and tax policy in mind.

Comment: In my country, things don't quite work like that. If you go into a "higher" tax slab, you only pay higher tax for that *extra* amount, not the whole amount. Ex: Let tax = 20% up to $1000, 30% for above $1000. For an income of $990, you pay $198. You get a raise of $20 (income = $1010), so you now pay (20% of $1000) + (30% of $10) = $203. So you still gained $15 overall. (For simplicity, I am not getting into tax saving investments and other interesting stuff.)

Comment: It's extraordinarily rare a raise bumping you up a tax bracket costs you more than the raise. usually it just means you get a bit less of an increase in effective income than you expected. Typically the only time I've seen raises refused is if there was new responsibilities or obligations tied to it that the person wasn't interested in.

Comment: @EricLippert While it's generally not a issue in the US at professional salary rates; for low income individuals the simultaneous phaseout of multiple forms of public assistance is ugly.  A 2012 study by the Congressional Budget Office found marginal effective tax rates peaking above 90% around the ~$18-20k range.  That study didn't capture several programs that have abrupt cutoffs where a small increase in earnings does result in a [net loss.](http://johnhcochrane.blogspot.com/2012/11/taxes-and-cliffs.html)

Comment: At the time I also recall reading that depending on the vagarities of state/local programs marginal rates >100% were possible even without benefit cliffs in some locales; but couldn't find any citations tonight.

Comment: I can imagine the specific income window where this may even be a problem has got to be extremely thin. Couldn't you simply explain to the employer "If my income goes up by x%, then it will cause a slight disadvantage for me due to the way the taxes work out. It would be better for us both if I could wait until I'm eligible for the x+0.5% raise." Maybe the employer is willing to increase by half a percentage or so to get you out of this "new tax scale penalty window".

Answer (score 1):

> Is it considered rude/unprofessional to reject a raise?

I don't think it would be rude. And I don't suspect it would be unprofessional.

What it would clearly be is unusual, and perhaps a bit odd. (At least in my part of the world).

Expect that you would be asked to explain your reasoning to the manager who gave you the raise.